# Matrix with rank 3 does not exist in this $p(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Given: Characteristic polynomial is $p(x) = x^7 - x^5 + x^3$ .

Prove that there isn't a matrix A that $ \rho(A) = 3 $

I tried to play with $p(x) = x^3(x^4 - x^2 +1)$ But I'm still not sure how to continue with that. Any ideas?

Comment: Where you wrote $3$, do you mean $3I?$ If you do, it's clearly false, just take $A=I$. If you don't, then the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant $p(A) = 3$

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS But If you write $p(A)=3$, then the LHS is a matrix and the RHS is a number. So such equations does not make much sense.

Comment: @ilan did you perhaps mean $rank(p(A))=3$?

Comment: I think the $p$ is supposed to be "rho" for rank, given the title and the issue is whether a matrix $A$ of rank $3$ can have the characteristic polynomial given.

Comment: I meant rank(A) = 3

Comment: $\rho(A) = 3$  ..

Comment: Is $p(x)$ supposed to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: yup. @GitGud  ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial shows that there are 4 distinct imaginary eigenvalues and 3 times eigenvalue 0.

Therefore the matrix $A$ has rank of at least 4.

Comment: Maybe you should write that rank is *at least 4*, instead of *$A$ has rank 4*. For example: $A=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & b & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & d & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$. (Only one Jordan block for zero.) Here $a,\dots,d$ denote the distinct non-zero roots of the given polynomial.

Comment: Good point! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

From $\deg p=7$ we conclude that $A\in k^{7\times 7}$.
For any polynomial $f\in k[X]$, the subspace $\ker f(A)$ is $A$-invariant. Especially, if $p=fg$ with $\gcd(f,g)=1$, we find $u,v\in k[X]$ with $uf+vg=1$ and see that $V=U\oplus W$ where $U=u(A)f(A)V=\ker g(A)$ and $W=v(A)g(A)V=\ker f(A)$. Moreover, the characteristic polynomial of $A|_U$ is $g$ and that of $A|_W$ is $f$. With $f=X^3$ and $g=X^4-X^2+1$, we find a subspace $U$ of dimension $4$ with an endomorphism $A|_U$ having characteristic polynomial $X^4-X^2+1$. From this we conclude that $A|_U$ is invertible with inverse $A|_U-(A|_U)^3$. But then $\rho(A)\ge \rho(A|_U)=4$.